Intent classification with wrong intent
I’ve been training my rasa model with few questions, but actually there is misclassification of intents which are not required.
For example I have two questions:
Q1. What is your biological gender?
Q2. What is your identifying gender?
Now the problem here is, the training examples for both are same, eg. Male, Female, Prefer not to say, etc.
So when the user types the “identifying gender” , the “biological gender” slot gets filled, that is not intended.
Can Anyone tell me how to resolve this, I’ve tried with Form actions and also changes like not_intent and ignore_intent, but none of them seems to work.
